# Node.js based Authentication & Authorisation framework?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Searching for such framework results mostly in Passport.js which I think is only good for authentication.

In PHP world, there is Sentry Cartalyst which is good for

- Authentication
- Authorisation (groups)
- List item
- User activation
- Password resetting
- Throttling

Is Node.js not mature enough to have such full-fledged open source framework?

Comment: in node, these tasks are usually split among several tools rather than one tool to do it all, allowing you to replace pieces of it to fine tune your application to your specific needs. Some of these parts will likely have to be built by hand though.

Comment: It seems more logical to group this functionality in one framework.

Comment: There are frameworks out there that do everything from routing to templating to authentication to db handling and modeling, if that's what you're looking for. I dislike all the ones currently available, so I won't list any of them.

Comment: Replacing can be done at the level of databases (like MongoDB or MySQL) and service providers (Mandrill or Sendgrid for emailing for example).

Comment: The problem with grouping all into one framework is the tasks you listed above have far more than authentication in mind. you have to have a templating engine to handle forms (and emails), a routing engine to handle the routes, models for user records and groups, and then there's the throttling which isn't related to any of the above. If the framework you find uses a different system for any of those things, that's extra bloat in your app.

Comment: Maybe you should stay with PHP.

Comment: node.js is in a kinda wild-west phase currently with how new and popular it is. There are a lot of new frameworks and tools being built, released, and often times abandoned.

Comment: I guess, what would be more useful for you is a generator that implements the things you need with the multiple tools available. Then, you can swap tools in and out for your specific needs (db driver, templating engine, etc)

Comment: @ivoszz Thinking actually of making an entry to Node world. Thought of starting a real application, with user management taken care of as quickly and focus on the application itself. I want to show it to a client.

Comment: If you don't want to manage a user database, I would try [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) (Disclaimer: I work there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js is built upon modules, which are built upon modules, etc. Frameworks in the normal sense don't really exist. Instead, what you have are starting points for applications, usually called Generators, and then you have modules that implement functionality. Generators of course are not required, you can instead start from scratch.

There are a few modules that do so much for you that they feel like frameworks, but at the end of the day they're just part of a whole, a module, that extends an existing module. Express is a great example of that. It wraps http.Server and handles the request callback for you, allowing you to chain callbacks onto a single request callback (called middleware) that eventually result in responding to the client with data (through routing).

But, all express does is routing. it doesn't do templating, emails, db work, authentication, data modeling, nothing. That all has to be added as middleware, and is usually done by using existing modules that implement that functionality.

Now, back to generators. Probably the most popular generator out there for Express is the [express generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html), however, all it comes with is express, a few essential pieces of middleware, error handling, and a templating engine. You're left with the task of installing and implementing other parts of the application (such as authentication) yourself. This is normal with node.js. At this point you would need to decide what you need for your app, how you want it implemented, and then find modules that accomplish those goals (or write modules yourself, because often times one doesn't exist that does precisely what you want.)

---

I said I wouldn't do this, but, [Loopback](http://loopback.io/) is another module and generator (the loopback devs call it a framework, I call it a generator, whatever) that builds an express app (wrapped in the loopback module), but it has almost all of the things you are looking for built-in. I don't use it because I feel it does too much. When my application was built with it, I felt uncomfortable with not knowing how the majority of the application worked, because I didn't build it, I just plugged in my data. It certainly saved time up front, but when it came to doing custom work that wasn't supported out of the box, it became very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a full CRUD user management system, you can't really beat something like Stormpath.

Using their express.js library instantly gives you a full CRUD system (with Node / Express / Restify / Loopback / Python / Django / Flask / etc...) libraries for managing / working with your users.

Here's their express.js library docs: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/

Essentially, what they do is:

- They'll store your user accounts.
- You use their middleware to create / login / manage users.
- You can use their middlewares to restrict pages by login, group, API authentication, etc.
- You can use their libraries to search / sort / create / update / delete users / API keys / applications / groups.
- It's very feature complete, and well documented.

I'm the author of the above library, so I'm a bit biased, but it's honestly quite useful =)